# Item do menu sempre aberto

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um menu lateral que quando o usuário clica altera a cor de um item selecionado no menu atravens de um codigo javascript, contudo quando acontece uma atualização na tela a classe é removida. Alguém teria alguma dica de como deixar com a cor selecionada após atualização da tela?

Queria que tivesse o mesmo comportamento do sbadmim https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

```js
   var selector2 = '.menu-section-list li';

    $(selector2).on('click', function () {
        console.log("s");
         $(selector2).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

[image: Menu]

Comment: da uma lida aqui:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060155/saving-website-styles-in-cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que no `sbadmin` cada opção do menu carrega uma página diferente que é exibida na `url`, com isso fica fácil verificar em que estado de tela está apenas verificando a `url`, que pode ser obtida com `window.location.href`.

Dito isto vale a pena dizer que o sbadmin utiliza o [metisMenu.js](https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu) e você pode estudar como isto está implementado ou simplesmente usá-lo também.